# Using rest service asp.net, Retrofit2, Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $,

Tags: android, .net, json, rest, service

I need help because when I use retrofit 2 and android for consuming my web service rest I get the error  Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $.
I think the error is because my rest service was developer in asp.net I have my code here.

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://190.165.1.122/amazonEbay/api/";
@GET("cliente")
Call<Catalogo> listaCatalogo();
```

the class Catalogo

```
public class Catalogo {
public List<client> CLIENTE;}
```

the class client

```
public class client {
public long CODIGO;
public String IDENTIFICACION;
public String NOMBREFACEBOOK;
public String NOMBRES;
public String APELLIDOS;
public String TELEFONO;
public String CIUDAD;
public String EMAIL;
```

}

And my rest service was published in IIS in my local store.

[Here you can see my rest service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htsei.png)

Please can you help me??

This is my response

```
public class pedido extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "Funciona: ";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pedido);
    Retrofit retrofit  = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(servicio.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    servicio service = retrofit.create(servicio.class);
    Call<Catalogo> requesCatalogo = service.listaCatalogo();
    requesCatalogo.enqueue(new Callback<Catalogo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Catalogo> call, Response<Catalogo> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.i("TAG", "Error" + response.code());
            }else {
                Catalogo catalogo = response.body();
                for (client c : catalogo.CLIENTE){
                   Log.i(TAG, String.format("%s: %s", c.APELLIDOS, c.IDENTIFICACION));
                    Log.i(TAG, "-------------");
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Catalogo> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it should be an array

Comment: paste your response

Comment: I I just edited my question

Comment: Post expected response

Comment: Take a look at the json response, the list of objects is probably inside a named object. You will need to create another pojo with that name containing a list of your Catalogo objects.

Comment: I am going to try this

Comment: I tried this but doesn't work